# Spark lazy transformation execution disorder

Tags: apache-spark, lazy-evaluation, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on SparkSQL. I used JavaPairRDD to get data from HBase and then did a map. In the map, I saved the all the keys into a Set. In order to force this map to be done, a collect() is followed. 
After this, I used the value in the Set to do other operations.

This program can work perfectly on my local PC. But when I put it onto the cluster(2 workers), there is an execution disorder. Before the map transformation, the Set operations are executed.

The code flow is like:
Get data from Hbase:

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBaseRDD =     jsc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbase_conf,
                TableInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
                Result.class);
```

Transform data:

```
JavaRDD<Map<String, String>> data = hBaseRDD.map(
                new Function<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>, Map<String, String>>(){
                    public Map<String, String> call(
                            Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> re)
                            throws Exception {
                        byte[] payload =re._2().getValue(Bytes.toBytes("ContentInfo"), Bytes.toBytes("Payload"));
                        Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

                        String primaryKey = new String(re._1().get());
                        map.put("primaryKey", primaryKey);

                        if(payload != null)
                            map.put("payload", new String(payload));

                        Map<byte[], byte[]> tmpMetaMap = re._2().getFamilyMap(Bytes.toBytes("MetaInfo"));
                        if(tmpMetaMap != null){
                            for(Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : tmpMetaMap.entrySet()){

                                String tmpKey = Bytes.toString(entry.getKey());
                                String tmpValue = Bytes.toString(entry.getValue());

                                map.put(tmpKey, tmpValue);
    //save result to the set
                                keySet.add(tmpKey);
                            }
                        }
                        return map;
                    }
                });
```

force the above map to run:

```
data.collect();
```

Get the result of the Set:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(String fieldName: keySet){

            sb.append(fieldName).append(",");
        }
```

When I run the code locally, I can get all the result. But when I run it on the cluster, sb has no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not related to ordering of operations but rather **where** in a cluster such operations are taking place.

In Spark, there're two types of operations: Transformations and Actions.

Transformations convert and RDD into another RDD by applying some function to the contents. This is a pure functional approach and is side-effect free.
Actions take an RDD and produce something else, like a file or a local data structure: These operations materialize the data of the RDD into some other form.

In this case, a transformation function: `map` is being used with side-effects, as `keyset` is expected to mutate during the map transformation. 
Given that `keyset` is defined outside the scope of the transformation function, it  will be serialized and sent to the executors but whatever mutations are happening remotely **WILL NOT** be recovered at the driver.

If we think about it, every executor will be applying the transformation on a partition of the data, so whatever content `keyset' ends with, will be only the partial view for each partition.

The proper way to model this is to redefine the operation in terms of RDD transformations and actions.

From the code above, it looks like we want to  transform some input into an `RDD[Map[String,String]]` and we are interested in collecting on the driver the set of keys across all entries that are not "primary key" and "payload" from that result.

In Spark this could be something like:

```
// data = RDD[Map[String, String]]
// first we get all the keys from all the maps
val keys = data.map{entry => entry.keys}
// now we collect that information on the driver
val allKeys = keys.collect
// we transform the resulting array into a set - this will remove duplicates by definition
val allKeySet = allKeys.toSet
// We need still to remove "primaryKey" and "payload"
val keySet = fullKeySet.diff(Set("primaryKey","payload"))
```

In Java the code is a bit more verbose, but the structure and idea is the same.

Comment: Another question: why the keySet value can be set when running locally?

Answer (score 0):

How you have defined keyset? Try to define it as static or otherwise use `foreach` instead of `map` which will bring all the data to the DriverSide.Hope this answer your question

Comment: Yes, I defined keySet as final static HashSet. 
I also tried with a simple foreach after the hBaseRDD. Just a foreach and nothing followed. It does not work on the spark server either.